# Problems with the parameterization for the "filename" text of CSV Data set config in jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter, filenames, beanshell

I understand that the CSV Data Set Config cannot use JMeter Variable as the "Filename", so I used the __property function as suggested in different posts:

- I defined an initial variable (datapoolpath) in the "User Defined Variable" config element
- I then converted my 'datapoolpath' variable in a property 'pdatapoolpath' in a BeanShell PreProcessor
- I used the ${__P(pdatapoolpath)} in the Filename field for the CSV Data Set Config

This workaround runs fine when I run the mytest with the Jmeter GUI.
As soon as I try to run the same test via cli (jmeter -n -t mytest,jmx -Jdatapool=c:\datapool), then it doesn't work anymore (ie: the csv data config is not able to find the csv file, since the property "pdatapoolpath" value is null. Please note, that in my BeanShell script I use to print the property's value, and still it seems to be correctly printed.

So my question is: where am I wrong? why jmeter behaves differently when run from GUI vs CLI?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables in the CSV Data Set Config field If it can get initialized in the UDV.

---

Assuming there is a file in the name and in the path `c:\datapool.csv`, by using `-J` - you are actually passing a `property` to the JMeter test ; not variable.

> ```
> -J, --jmeterproperty {argument}={value}
>             Define additional JMeter properties
> ```

If you invoke like this

`jmeter -n -t mytest.jmx -Jdatapool=c:\datapool.csv`

You can directly use this in the CSV Data Set Config by using the property name passed in the commandline.

```
${__P(datapool)}
```

If you need to copy this property to a User Defined Variable,

```
vdatapool = ${__P(datapool)}
```

then access the variables as given below in the CSV data set config.

```
${vdatapool}
```

---

This is how we need to access variables and properties in JMeter.

`${variablename}`

`${__P(proprtyname)}`

Comment: Thank you for your clarification,Vinoth, it helps a lot. I have one more question on this topic. Assume I want to compose the 'pdatapool' property from a property I pass trough the CLI, as for example: jmeter -n -t mytest.jmx -Jmyworkpath=C:\workdir    and then, within the mytext.jmx initialize the 'pdatapool' property as ${__P(myworkpath)}\datapool.... Where I should initializing it to be used then successfully as filename in the CSV Data Set config? I've defined in a BeanShell pre processor but with no success. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In Beanshell, `props.put("pdatapool", props.get("myworkpath") + "\datapool");`

Comment: Thank you, but it looks like it does not work. Even if I can see the new property ("pdatapool") is correct (I see it from the trace), still my CSV Data Set Config plugin reads from a wrong path (the Filename in the plugin is defined as follow: ${__P(pdatapool)}\my.csv.   It looks like the "pdatapool" property is initialized *after* the CSV plugin is executed, even if I used the BeanShell Pre Processor.